# Confirm these 301 redirects are correctly setup in my htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I need to create a few 301 redirects for a site, basically I need to redirect the following URL :

```
http://www.oldsite.com/en-gb/resources/ks2/
```

to

```
http://www.newsite.com/resources/ks2/
```

I think the following should be sufficient, can anyone confirm this

```
Redirect 301 http://www.oldsite.com/en-gb/resources/ks2/ http://www.newsite.com/resources/ks2/
```

Does this look correct? As it scanned by Google's bot I want to get it correct first time round, thanks  in advance

P.S What is the best way/resource people use to confirm their 301 redirects are correctly setup?

Comment: Use a temporary redirect for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is incorrect since you only match `Request URI` in the rule. Also better to use `RedirectMatch` for regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en-gb/(resources/ks2/?)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1
```